# Swift 3 - invalid JSON object of [[String: Any]]

Tags: arrays, dictionary, swift3

I have this instance:

```
var commands = [[String: Any]]()
```

After some calculations, its result is:

```
[["command": 50022, "homes": [["gateways": [["mac": "845DD74B405E", "services": [["iid": 9, "name": "Some name"]], "aid": 1]], "name": "H1"]]], ["command": 50025, "services": [["mac": "845DD74B405E", "iid": 9, "aid": 1, "new_name": "Some name"]]]]
```

I want to convert it (`commands`) to JSON using [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON):

```
let json = JSON(commands)
print(json) // "unknown"
```

but the result is always `unknown`.

Then I check the validity of `commands` to make sure it is JSON-convertable. But I got `false` with `JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(commands)`, which is unexpected!

Do you have any ideas why `commands` (array of Dictionary) is NOT a valid `JSON` object?

Thanks

Comment: Your array is valid.

Comment: I agree with you that the array is valid (I verified it by `print(type(of: commands))` -> array). But what confuses me is: if it is valid, then how come it is not a valid JSON object?

Comment: It's also a valid JSON object. I proved it in a playground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my `commands` is at the integer numbers, `50022` and `50025`. In my code, they are defined in an `enum` of `UInt32`. And when I copied them to a playground to verify, Swift converts it to `Int`. That is why I always succeed in playground.

Back to my code, Swift 3 expects a number to be an `Int` in order to convert it to a JSON object successfully. Swift 2 does not have this behavior.

So, after I change my `enum` define from `UInt32` to `Int`, it just works beautifully!

Thanks everyone.